# The qml default signal handler cannot work

Tags: components, signals, qml

---Question---

I create a "TextBtn" component and add a signal "btnClicked" in it:

TextBtn.qml

---

```
import Qt 4.7

Rectangle {
    property alias btnText: showStr.text
    width:100
    height:30
    border.color: "black"
    border.width: 1
    color: "white"
    signal btnClicked()
    //the default signal handler
    onBtnClicked: console.log(btnText+" is clicked.")
    MouseArea {
        id: btnMouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: btnClicked()
    }
    Text {
        id: showStr
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        color: "black"
    }
}
```

Another component "MenuRow" contains three "TextBtn"s as follows:

MenuRow.qml

---

```
import Qt 4.7

Row {
    spacing: 5
    TextBtn {
        id: testBtn01
        btnText: "test01"
    }
    TextBtn {
        id: testBtn02
        btnText: "test02"
    }
    TextBtn {
        id: testBtn03
        btnText: "test03"
    }
}
```

The default single handler "onBtnClicked" in "TextBtn" should be triggered when one of "TextBtn"s in "MenuRow" is clicked, but it doesn't. What's going on?

The related qml doc is here: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/gettingstartedqml.html#basic-component-a-button

---Development Environment---

OS: Ubuntu 10.04

Qt Version: 4.7.0(Use "qt-sdk-linux-x86-opensource-2010.05.1.bin" to install qt sdk in the default path "$HOME/qtsdk-2010.05/")

Before running qml, I source a file "qtsetup.sh" to set the related paths,

```
$ source qtsetup.sh
```

qtsetup.sh

---

```
QTDIR=$HOME/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/
PATH=$PATH:$QTDIR/bin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$QTDIR/lib
```

then run qml files with "qmlviewer".

```
$ qmlviewer MenuRow.qml
```

A qmlviewer window is triggered and shows the "MenuRow". No error occurs. I use mouse to click "TextBtn" in "MenuRow", but nothing happens. (It should show a message "text0X is clicked" in the terminal.)

I use qmlviewer to run other examples and demos, they seem to work well. I don't know why this example cannot work.

Comment: Hate to say it, but that code "works for me"...  must be something else you're not telling us...

Comment: Thanks, funkybro. Maybe I need to describe more details about how I run qml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem happens here too (qmlviewer 4.7.0).

Looks like it's a bug in qmlviewer, read the follow-ups [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/qt-qml@trolltech.com/msg01709.html).

If you remove your alias (btnText), the signal will work. (But the proper solution is update to 4.7.1+)